# Force bgSave() using Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-redis

Is there any way to call bgSave() (force writing to disk) using Spring Data Redis Repositories?

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
}
```

I've gone through the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:connectors:jedis) but I couldn't find any reference about bgSave(). The only way I can think of would be by autowiring RedisConnectionFactory, getting the RedisConnection and calling the method, although I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: The only way is to inject `RedisConnection` and call `bgSave()`.

Comment: Ok so I was doing it right, I replaced Jedis for Redis because it could be any of its implementations. Thanks!